# can't use exclamation mark (!) in bash

Tags: bash

so i tried to substitute history command in bash with exclamation mark

```
raihan@Saria:~$ alias cd='cd \!*;echo $cwd'
raihan@Saria:~$ ls Desktop/
raihan@Saria:~$ cd
bash: cd: !*: No such file or directory
hello world
```

How do I have to write the statement?

Comment: Just replace ' by ": `alias cd="cd \!*;echo $cwd"`

Comment: what is replaced with "by" ?

Comment: you used single quote `'` , but you need to use double quote `"`

Comment: I've tried it with " but after checking it turns back to '

Comment: Strange, i tried on Ubuntu and it works only with double quote, which linux distribution you use?

Comment: same i use ubuntu

Comment: Oh yes sorry my bad, when you use double quote you don't need to escape `!` with \ so your alias need to be `alias cd="cd !*;echo $cwd"`, and now it will be work for sure

Comment: sorry but somehow still not working. His exclamation mark is not detected. and when I checked again, the exclamation mark disappeared

Comment: Ok it's impossible to use `!` in an alias [source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103835/why-does-inside-an-alias-not-work)